# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flag is not initialized google ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Flag is not initialized.
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.flag.a.a(a.java:9)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.report.d.a(d.java:1)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.state.i.a(i.java:14)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.DynamiteOmid.initializeOmid(DynamiteOmid.java:8)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.b.a(b.java:41)
```

I am getting this crash on the initialization of my app by looking at the logs I believe it has something to do with [OMID](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/open-measurement)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Same issue for me. I'm using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0`, trying to downgrade now.

Comment: Abhishek, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I am using sdk version 19.4.0

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/4lER8wb6sfA/m/A9_qU6sfAAAJ

Comment: @abhishek92 I am facing the same issue. Do you get anything ?